# Getting environment variables in PHP-FPM with Nginx

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, environment-variables, env

I've defined some environment variables like `APP_ENV` in my `/etc/environment` file, on my ArchLinux.

If I type `printenv`, I see them.

I've created this simple test file called… `test.php`

```
<?php

var_dump(getenv('APP_ENV'));
var_dump(getenv());
```

If I run `php test.php`, everything is OK, I see my ENV variables.

But when I try to access the file via HTTP… there is nothing in my env!

Of course, I've changed the config of `/etc/php/php-fpm.d/www.conf` to set `clear_env = no`

These are the affected lines:

```
; Clear environment in FPM workers
; Prevents arbitrary environment variables from reaching FPM worker processes
; by clearing the environment in workers before env vars specified in this
; pool configuration are added.
; Setting to "no" will make all environment variables available to PHP code
; via getenv(), $_ENV and $_SERVER.
; Default Value: yes
clear_env = no
```

And I've restarted both `php-fpm` and `nginx` services but… still nothing in my env.  Script return `bool(false)`.

So… Am I missing something ?

This is my php-fpm version:

```
php-fpm --version
PHP 7.2.6 (fpm-fcgi) (built: May 26 2018 07:45:18)
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

And my Nginx version

```
nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0
```

What should I do to access my env variables in a PHP-FPM context ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the environment variable in /etc/php/php-fpm.d/www.conf like this:
`env[APP_ENV] = development`
Then you'll be able to get it with `getenv('APP_ENV')` like you expected.

Comment: This works, but I don't think the www.conf file is meant to be used like that

Comment: This blows my mind.  I'm not going to put my secrets into a web config file!

Comment: I agree. Sensitive information shouldn't go there and my suggestion to add it to a .conf file was a quick way to achieve what they needed because it was a server related setting (APP_ENV).I suspect that the original problem is related to which user PHP-FPM is running as

Comment: The PHP-FPM user is probably not sourcing the environment variables. I can't really come up with another way of doing this. I usually use Kubernetes, which injects the env vars from the pod definition and they do work with all users, in my experience.

One thing you can try is to modify the systemctl service to source and export the variables before launching the server, but it's rather hacky.

Answer (score 2):

When you type printenv or php test.php, you see environnement variables because they exist.

When you "try to access the file via HTTP… there is nothing in [your] env". Exactly your environnement variables are not set.

Why would you expect a different behaviour? Files like /etc/environment, /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc are only sourced when you use a shell, not when a daemon is ran.

Comment: how would you centralize env var to use both for php cli scripts and php scripts executed by a webserver?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to create a php file such as

```
<? $_SERVER['APP_ENV]='dev';
```

somewhere on disk, and have it included via php.ini setting `auto_prepend_file`.
Not too clean, but it might help avoiding storing secrets in php-fpm config...

Rationale:

it seems the php documentation for fpm config is not very clear about how `clear_env` and `env` supposed to work in the pool config file.

In my own experience:

- the environment variables which will be made available to the workers when `clear_env = no` are the ones for the user defined in the pool, which is generally not the root user
- defining environment variables for that user in places such as .bashrc will not work, as the worker processes will not read the same environment configuration scripts as a shell does
- it seems that, depending on how php-fpm is actually started (via an init.d script / systemd / direct invocation of the executable via f.e. a custom Docker CMD), the env variables might, or not, show up

Adding insult to injury, it is very hard to get the documented syntax `env[APP_ENV] = $APP_ENV` to work, so the only way to have a value show up is to harcode it in fpm pool configuration. But that might be not the best solution for all scenarios